# How can I make apigility display exception trace in ApiProblem responses?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

In the module.config.php files for zf-api-problem and zf-rest it says you can override 'display_exceptions' in the application config to get exception stack traces in the response.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    // Enable this in your application configuration in order to get full
    // exception stack traces in your API-Problem responses.
    'display_exceptions' => false,
),
```

I have display_exceptions set to true in my Application module.config.php (from the skeleton app), however it gets overwritten when all the configs are merged. When I look at the state of the config in \ZF\ApiProblem\Listener\SendApiResponseListener, where the ApiProblemResponse is being constucted, 'display_exceptions' is set to false.

Is it merging in zf-api-problem and zf-rest configs after the application config and overwriting it?

How can I enable display_exceptions without changing it in the vendor modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable development mode,  The apigility copy The `./config/development.config.php.dist` to `./config/development.config.php`. This is merged with another configs. So, edit The .dist file, and disable and enable the development mode.

Comment: I ended up making another .local.php config file and putting it in config/autoload. You're right that I needed to do this config at the application level instead of in the module

Answer (score 0):

You could be right that the settings are overwritten by another config.
Try once to change the order of your application modules. So in your `application.config.php`:

```
<?php

return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZF\Hal',
        'ZF\Rest',
        'ZF\ApiProblem',

        ... more modules ...

        'My\Custom\Module'  // --> Set your 'display_exceptions' => true 
                            //     in the module.config.php of this module
    )
)
```

Comment: The best place to make this is in development.config.php or the local.php